# replace comma with colon in csv file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

In CSV file all other delimiters are comma except for 1 colon.
While saving this CSV,  excel replaces this colon to comma.

How can I overcome this? or Later how can I replace those particular comma with colon?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from Excel?
Can you post an example of your CSV file?

Comment: Here is example file: http://www.sendspace.com/file/p6a4fj

Comment: I have tried saving the sample you provided to each of the possible csv formats available in excel and have not seen the : be replaced. do you have a sample of a file where this has occurred also?